# want to fetch sorted documents of two certain ids using mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i have a mongodb collection named 'Scores' and the inputs in the collection are of format:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5aa59c8411c5de25042a06fd"),
id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAC,
score:2},{
_id: ObjectId("5aa59c8b11c5de25042a06fe"),
id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAC,
score: 5},{
_id: ObjectId("5aa59c9511c5de25042a06ff"),
id:  pkCJGv23JobXVAXRAAAE,
score:7},{
 _id: ObjectId("5aa59d9f11c5de25042a0703"),
 id: pkCJGv23JobXVAXRAAAE,
 score:9},{
 _id: ObjectId("5aa59d9411c5de25042a0701"),
 id: fwCB0sJMCpsmN44ZAWPF,
 score:3},{
 _id: ObjectId("5aa59d9f11c5de25042a0703"),
 id:pkCJGv23JobXVAXRAAAE,
 score: 12},{
 _id: ObjectId("5aa59d9411c5de25042a0701"),
 id: fwCB0sJMCpsmN44ZAWPF,
  score:7 }
```

The collection has various objects with various 'id' , I just want to fetch the documents of two certain  ids and sort them based on score. Like on the basis of the above collection , i want the highest 'score' of

```
id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAC, id:pkCJGv23JobXVAXRAAAE
```

..and not the of the other ids. The expected output should be:

```
{score:9}, {score:12}
```

Can you tell me how will this be possible using aggregation ?

Comment: You want to `$match` on id, `$group` using `$max`, and then `$sort`, then `$project` to remove the id field again. What version of mongodb are you using. Here are their docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/

Comment: filter documents in a **`$match`** stage, then sort the document in a **`$sort`** stage, and finally keep only the `score` field using a **`$project`** stage

Comment: I am using 3.6 version and btw thanks for the help!

Comment: may be you need **db.coll.find({id : {$in : ["id1", id2]}},{score : 1}).sort({score : 1})**

Comment: @achuth that won't give the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.score.aggregate([
 {$match: {id:{$in:["Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAC","pkCJGv23JobXVAXRAAAE"]}}},
 {$group:{_id:"$id", score:{$max:"$score"}}},
 {$project:{_id:0,score:1}}

])
```

And output is:

```
{
"score" : 12
}

{
"score" : 5
}
```

It is not certainly `{score:9}, {score:12}` if you cross check your collections.

Comment: thanks @Rahul Raj. and btw is there any way such that the order in which the ids are mentioned in the match ,in the same order the output is given and not like the highest score between both the ids first and then one to follow

Comment: You can't track the the order in which input matches are given. However if you need to sort `score` in ascending order, you can do it by adding additional stage `{$sort:{score:1}}` in the pipeline after the final projection stage

Comment: but what if i need it according to the order of inputs? i googled now n i found that $addfields help us in achieving this

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/ where exactly its mentioned about order of inputs? `$addFields` operator is equivalent to `$project` only difference is that you can only modify/add fields unlike the `$project` can remove fields also.

Comment: .I achieved in my projet now like this:   var order =[data.id,data.enemy_id];
        db.collection('Scores').aggregate([
            {$match: {id:{$in:order}}},
            {$addFields: {"__order": {$indexOfArray: [order, "$id" ]}}},
            {$sort: {"__order": 1}},
            {$group: {_id:'$id',score:{$max:'$score'}}},
            {$project: {_id:0,score:1}}
        ]).toArray().then((docs)=>{
            var score1 = JSON.stringify(docs,undefined,2);
            var score1 = JSON.parse(score1);
            console.log(score1);
        });

Comment: I mentioned it in my answer comment. Btw thanks for your guidance sir!

Answer (score 0):

The output in the order of inputs using aggregation :

```
   var order =[data.id,data.enemy_id];
    db.collection('Scores').aggregate([
        {$match: {id:{$in:order}}},
        {$addFields: {"__order": {$indexOfArray: [order, "$id" ]}}},
        {$sort: {"__order": 1}},
        {$group: {_id:'$id',score:{$max:'$score'}}},
        {$project: {_id:0,score:1}}
    ]).toArray().then((docs)=>{
        var score1 = JSON.stringify(docs,undefined,2);
        var score1 = JSON.parse(score1);
        console.log(score1);
    });
```